# Reassigning last index of an array in loop

Tags: python

I'm a little bit confused about why the function below works. I'm trying to shift any array over by n times. I do this by creating a new array with the same length of the original array, and replace the values in the array accordingly.

```
test = [6,1,4,7,8]

def shiftArray(input_array, n):
    max_len = len(input_array)
    max_idx_len = len(input_array)-1
    
    shifted_array = [None]*max_len

    for i in range(0, max_len):
        if i == 0:
            shifted_array[i] = input_array[max_len-n]
        else:
            shifted_array[i] = input_array[i-n]
    return shifted_array

print(shiftArray(test,1))
```

I originally had the range for the for loop be `range(0, max_idx_len)`, which is what made sense to me since an array's index starts at 0. But when I did that, the last value of the array was never replaced. So instead, I did `range(0, max_len)` which worked. But I still don't understand why.

There are 5 values in this array, and a max index of 4, so when I reassign the last index of `shifted_array` - shouldn't I be reassigning `shifted_array[4]` instead of `shifted_array[5]`? Why does this work!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check how the `range` function works. `range(0,10)` will only iterate 10 times from 0 to 9. It will not go till 10.

So `range(0, max_idx_len)` will only iterate till `max_idx_len-1` which is why the last value of the array was never being replaced.

Hope that answers your question.